# Big Query Regexp_Extract using Google Analytics url

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I extract the id parameter below using Big Query `Regexp_Extract` some rows with page urls in them that look similar to : 
url.com/id=userIDmadeUPofletterandnumbers&em=MemberType
eg url.com/id=asd1221231sf&em=studentMember

I have tried using: 
a. `REGEXP_EXTRACT(urlValue,"id=\w+")` as Idvalue but I get the error message: 
 Invalid string literal: "id=\w+"

I am pretty close with this: REGEXP_EXTRACT(urlValue,"(id=.*&em)") however it shows me `id=asd1221231sf&em` and I want to exclude `id=` and &em at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'url.com/id=userIDmadeUPofletterandnumbers&em=MemberType' urlValue UNION ALL
  SELECT 'url.com/id=asd1221231sf&em=studentMember'
)
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(urlValue, r'id=(\w+)') id, urlValue
FROM `project.dataset.table`

Row id                              urlValue     
1   userIDmadeUPofletterandnumbers  url.com/id=userIDmadeUPofletterandnumbers&em=MemberType  
2   asd1221231sf      url.com/id=asd1221231sf&em=studentMember
```

Comment: Thanks ! Any idea why adding that extra `r` at the beginning of the Regex makes it work - I can't see a link to it in the documentation

Comment: those are so called `raw strings` you can check them [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#string-and-bytes-literals)